# In Qt Widgets Application, cannot change value of `QSpinBox` after `setValue` in overloaded `paintEvent`?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

#### Problem

In an Qt Widgets Application, I cannot change the value of my `QSpinBox` after I `setValue` for it in overloaded `paintEvent` of `MainWindow`.

Thanks to @eyllanesc , I will emphasize the question.

My question is: **why** I can not change the value of my `QSpinBox` after I `setValue` for it in overloaded `paintEvent` of `MainWindow`?

#### Reproduce the issue

I can reproduce the issue in the following steps.

1. Create a QtWidget Application by Qt Creator
2. Create a `QSpinBox` by embedded Qt Designer
3. Add following code to `mainwindow.h`:

   `void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);`
4. Add following code to `mainwindow.cpp`:

   `void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) { ui->spinBox->setValue(2); }`
5. Build and run the application.
6. Try to change the value of the spinBox and you will find you cannot change the value.

I can move my function `setValue` to another place to avoid this issue, but **why** this happen? I can't find what mistake that I make.

#### Trials

- I tested `QDoubleSpinBox` and `QLineEdit`, they behave similarly.
- Trying to `setReadOnly(false)`, it doesn't work.
- When I try to change the value, I get signal of `valueChanged(int)` emiting, but `setValue(int)` does not work anymore.
- I read [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5) about `QPaintEvent` and `QAbstractSpinBox`. I can't find anything useful.

Help me please!

#### Environments

- OS: Windows10
- Qt Compiler: Desktop Qt 5.11.1 MinGW 32bit

#### Source Code

The complete source code can be found in [mainwindow.h](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/mBsCMX79K9/), [main.cpp](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7Fc7FgpTcM/), [mainwindow.cpp](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/dkVNZG3jq9/), [mainwindow.ui](https://pastebin.com/pMr8cX43).

Comment: My question is: why do you do the following? `void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) { ui->spinBox->setValue(2); }`

Comment: @eyllanesc This is a simplified consequence from my project. As mentioned in my question, I could avoid it at all. But I want **a reason why not to use it**. Because the simplification to find that it is exactly the problem from a large project took me several hours! Thanks for commenting.

Comment: @eyllanesc Thx and I know [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) now. My question is exactly: why the value of `spinBox` is stuck after I do that? I can't understand it at all. If possible, I want some reasons, or, just tell me that I have not to do that, without any explanation and documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Why can not the value of the QSpinBox be changed if the change is made in the paintEvent method?**

Because you are creating an infinite loop within the asynchronous part of the application.

When any GUI value is updated so that the user can see it then it must be repainted, and for this the developer calls `update()`, that method internally sends the event `QEvent::Paint`, and in the case of events these are sent to all widgets from parent to child, in that case the `QEvent::Paint` event arrives first at the MainWindow and then possibly reaches your child's spinbox. It is only passed on to the children if the parent uses it. Then the sequence is as follows:

1. The user changed the value of the `QSpinbox`
2. It's called `update()`
3. The `QEvent::Paint` event is sent to the window, and it redistributes it to the children.
4. It reaches the MainWindow, changes the value and goes to step 2.

In conclusion if you change the value of the spinbox, it will indirectly call the paintEvent method of the MainWindow and set the spinbox to the previous value. **The task of paintEvent(...) is only to paint**, not to update another value, if it does it will probably create an infinite loop.